# Excel not updating when a PowerShell script is run from c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following PowerShell script that I am trying to run from c#.

The Script takes two parameters that are being passed from the C# code, and the PowerShell script is being loaded properly.

```
param([string]$csvFile, [string]$xlpath)
$processes = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile -header "LIMSINVOICENR","JOBID","CUSTOMERID","POREFERENCE","CURRENCY","ITEM","DETAILS","QTY","UNITPRICE"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $false 
$workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($xlpath)
$workbook.Sheets.Item("SalesOrders").Activate() | Out-Null

$i = 5 
$unit = $excel.cells.item($i,14).Text
foreach($process in $processes) first line of the CSV file
{ 
    $excel.cells.item($i,4) = $process.LIMSINVOICENR
    $excel.cells.item($i,5) = $process.JOBID
    $excel.cells.item($i,6) = $process.CUSTOMERID
    $excel.cells.item($i,7) = $process.POREFERENCE
    $excel.cells.item($i,8) = $process.CURRENCY
    $excel.cells.item($i,9) = $process.ITEM
    $excel.cells.item($i,10) = $process.DETAILS
    $excel.cells.item($i,11) = $process.QTY
    $excel.cells.item($i,12) = $process.UNITPRICE

    $excel.cells.item($i,14) = $unit
    $i++ 
}

$workbook.Save() | Out-Null
$workbook.Close() | Out-Null
$Excel.Quit() 

Remove-Variable -Name excel 
[gc]::collect() 
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

I am attempting to use the `System.Management.Automation` library, by using the following commands:

```
    public void UpdateWorksheet(string FullCsvFilePath, string FullWorksheetFilePath)
    {
        String powershellScript = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "UpdateToAX.PS1";

         using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {

            PowerShellInstance.AddCommand(powershellScript);
            PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("csvFile", FullCsvFilePath);
            PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("xlpath", FullWorksheetFilePath);
            PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

The script is run and the CSV file is being read but it looks that the Excel file isn't being read from or written to. The script worked independently when not called from the C# program.

The following is run before the UpdateWorksheet process:

```
    public void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        this._MessageLog.SaveToLogFile("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

        try
        {
            String FullWorksheetName = SystemWriter.CreateWorksheet(XMLSettings.TemplateFileName, e.Name.Remove(e.Name.Length -4, 4), XMLSettings.OutputFilePath);
            SystemWriter.UpdateWorksheet(e.FullPath, FullWorksheetName);
            this._MessageLog.SaveToLogFile("File: " + e.FullPath + " Uploaded to " + FullWorksheetName);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            this._MessageLog.SaveToLogFile("Error Updating the '" + e.Name + "' Worksheet : " + exception.Message);
        }
    }

    public String CreateWorksheet(string TemplateFileFullName, string CsvFileName, string WorkingDirectoryPath)
    {
        string WorkFileName = CsvFileName + ".xlsx";

        //copy and rename the template file to the working directory
        File.Copy(TemplateFileFullName, WorkingDirectoryPath + WorkFileName);

        return WorkingDirectoryPath + WorkFileName;
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to stop through it with a debugger?  Is `UpdateWorksheet` called from within a try/catch that isn't in the question?

Comment: Yes, I stepped through it, but no errors were shown. The parent proces of this has a try catch, which isn't showing any error.